# Laravel REST API with Polymorphic Relationship with nested JSON

Tags: php, rest, laravel, vue.js

I have 2 models, Games and Images.  When I query '/games' in my API, I am returning JSON for all of the Games in the database. How should I query the DB in my GamesController to pass down the Image associated with the Game without explicitly creating an "image_url" column in my Game model? Is that the only way?  I would like to nest like this:

```
{
 id: 1,
 title: 'Halo 5',
 image: {
      url: 'http://theimageurlhere.com',
      imageable_id: 1,
      imageable_type: 'App\Game'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Games model you need write something like this:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Images', 'imageable_id', 'id')
        ->whereImageableType('App\Game');
}
```

And when you take your games:

```
return Games::select()
        ->with('images')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Checking this out now. I will let you know. Thank you for your answer rather than a downvote :)

Comment: This was pretty close to what I was looking for.  I was able to find out more information about eager loading in Laravel 5 and got this to work.  Thanks a ton! It definitely gets lost in the documentation on Laravel so this was greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If someone happens to find this, this is what I ended up having to do. I am using Laravel 5.3:

```
/*Game Model*/

public function images()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Image', 'imageable');
}

/*Image Model*/

public function imageable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

/*Games Controller*/

public function index()
{
    $games = Game::with('images')->get();

    return $games;
}

=====================================
Here is the JSON it returns:
{
    id: 1,
    title: "As she said to.",
    slug: "as-she-said-to",
    description: "Consequatur at qui iusto.",
    created_at: "2016-09-29 12:04:36",
    updated_at: "2016-09-29 12:04:36",
    images: [
        {
            id: 1,
            url: "http://www.mobygames.com/images/covers/l/281002-rayman-legends-xbox-one-front-cover.png",
            imageable_id: 1,
            imageable_type: "App\Game",
            created_at: "2016-09-29 12:04:36",
            updated_at: "2016-09-29 12:04:36"
         }
      ]
    }

========================================
Then in my Vue.js front-end:

<img v-bind:src="game.images[0].url" class="img-responsive"/>
```

Comment: This is called eager loading, FYI